# AddChart() throws when presentation is opened with WithWindow = false

Tags: charts, powerpoint, office-interop

I'm not sure if this is "intended", or if a workaround (other than showing the presentation) exists.

```
#if DEBUG
    var withWindow = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
#else
    // using msoTrue fixes the error
    var withWindow = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
#endif

    presentation = app.Presentations.Open(templateFileName,
        Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, // readonly
        Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, // untitled (?)
        withWindow // with window: visible or not
        );

// some time later...
slide.Shapes.AddChart(); // Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. ErrorCode: -214747259
```

Not being able to have the PowerPoint presentation hidden when automating is pretty annoying. Are there any workarounds for this issue?